# Getting 'User does not have BROWSE_PROJECTS permission' for Cloud Zephr Sqaud REST API

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

i am using free trial version of JIRA Cloud , i am trying to a new cycle for zephr Squad but getting

> User does not have BROWSE_PROJECTS permission to perform the operation on project 2 issue
> Response code: 403

Response:

```
{
    "errorType": "ERROR",
    "clientMessage": "User does not have BROWSE_PROJECTS permission to perform the operation on project 2 issue .",
    "errorCode": 169
}
End Point - https://prod-api.zephyr4jiracloud.com/connect/public/rest/api/1.0/cycle
Headers-
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiI...
zapiAccessKey:amlyYTo3YjU3OTBhN...
Body:
{ "name": "QAUT Cycle 1", "environment": "QA", "description": "This contains regression tests", "startDate": "2023-10-05", "endDate": "2023-10-10", "clearCustomFieldsFlag": true, "projectId": 2 }
```

I have admin access.

[image]